# Log before un-handled exception is thrown in apache camel

Tags: exception, apache-camel

My errorHandlder code looks as below:

```
    errorHandler(defaultErrorHandler().maximumRedeliveries(retry)
                    .redeliveryDelay(delayMs).asyncDelayedRedelivery().retryAttemptedLogLevel(LoggingLevel.WARN));
```

This just throws the exceptions as they come and the stack trace is logged as expected. But before logging the stacktrace, i want to add a custom message. I want my log to be "My custom message" + exception stacktrace. Both should be a single entity.

Answer (score 0):

The most simple way is probably to just add the Log additional statement to your [ErrorHandler](http://camel.apache.org/error-handler.html).

```
errorHandler(transactionErrorHandler() 
    ...
    .log("My custom message");
```